# how to receive a multi select in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I have a multi select that looks like this

```
input.form-control(type='text', name='names[]')
```

I want to retrieve does values. I'm using this

```
var names = req.body.names[];
```

Obviously that not working. How do i get the values of an array using expressjs.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need `req.body['names[]']`, though BodyParser should parse this and `req.body.names` should be an array.

Comment: That solved my problem thanks. I wish I can vote you as the answer but I don't think you can do it with comments

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, credit Ben Fortune:

You'll need `req.body['names[]']`, though `BodyParser` should parse this and `req.body.names` should be an array.